# c#: public when debugging, private otherwise

Tags: c#, debugging, nunit, access-modifiers

Is there a nice way to make it so that functions are public when I am testing with NUnit, but private otherwise?

Not having to generate a lot of extraneous code would also be nice.

------------------------Edit------------------------

It seems the solutions fall under 3 types:

1. don't do what I'm attempting to do.
2. use compiler directives.
3. try a clever solution (like using
   InternalsVisibleTo).

Might there be a way to do this programmatically?  i.e. just create a new temporary app that makes all `protected/private/internal`functions `public`, plug that into NUnit, run the tests there, and then go back to using the private functions for the release version?

Comment: Have you tried using `internal`?

Comment: If you need to unit test a method then it should be public in the first place.

Comment: What you want to do shouldn't be done.  You are just asking for trouble.  Like Carnotaurus suggests, if a method needs a unit test then it should already be public.

Comment: Just a note: Best practice is to avoid "#if DEBUG" statements as so many have suggested.

Comment: Why would you want to expose certain methods to other developers?  Isn't it better to be more thorough with your testing?

Comment: @Tedd: I agree, but I'm not sure why.  Where did you read/hear about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might not need to if you have good coverage on your public methods which call the private methods but that seems to be another debate into it self.

This is a good link about TDD and different ways to do it:
[How to Test Private and Protected methods in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/testnonpublicmembers.aspx)

Comment: Interesting discussion.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `private`<->`public` you can make them `internal`<->`public` using [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx).

`InternalsVisibleTo` is an assembly attribute that you can use in the assembly you want to make visible to your unit test assembly. You will have to sign your unit test assembly, because the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute relies on the public key of the calling assembly.

Comment: Hm... this is interesting.  I was looking for something like this a while back.  You would also need use System.Runtime.CompilerServices to get this to work.  But it doesn't solve the problem of making it private within the assembly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's always `internal` as others have pointed out, but since that's distinct from both `private` and `public` (and hence could affect other code in the same assembly), why not use compiler directives:

```
#define DEBUG
//...

#if DEBUG
public int PublicMethod(int x, int y)
{
    return privateMethod(x, y);
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private int MethodToTest() {...}

#if DEBUG
public int MethodTested()
{
   return MethodToTest();
}
#endif
```

Test MethodTested()

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#if DEBUG
public type MethodName(parameters)
#else
private type MethodName(parameters)
#endif
{
 // method body
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shortly, try this:

```
#if DEBUG
public 
#else
private 
#endif
int myMethod(params)
{
   // do something.
}
```

usa as myMethod();